# Create Hyperlinks through Json Document

Tags: javascript, json

I apologize in advance if this is a really simple request that has already been answered and I am just too unfamiliar with javascript to understand.

I would like to create a json catalog that displays on an HTML page as a table and I would like for one of the cells to be a hyperlink, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Here is my json script:

```
"beer": [{
    "name": "NAME",
    "type": "TYPE",
    "company": "BREWERY",
    "website": "WWW.SITE.COM",
    "price": 6.00
}],
```

and this is my HTML script

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","catalog.json",false);
xmlhttp.send();
json=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

document.write("<table class=table table-bordered>");
var x=json.beer;
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(x[i].name);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].type);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].company);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].website);
document.write("</td><td>$");
document.write(x[i].price.toFixed(2));                                    
document.write("</td></tr>");
 }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Can anyone help with this

Comment: This doesn't require complex javascript.  You're building some HTML and inserting data from the json into it -- right now you're building `<td>www.example.com</td>` and presumably what you want is `<td><a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a></td>`.  You can change your code to produce that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, *don't* use `document.write`.  If called after the page is done loading, it will **erase** the entire page.  Better to use DOM methods to add new elements.

Second, AJAX is (supposed to be) asynchronous, why are you passing `false` to `.open()`?  (P.S. I doubt anyone is gonna be accessing this site with IE5/6, so you can lose the `new ActiveXObject`)

```
// In 2014, this is all that's really needed
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

// The callback to run when the request is done
xhr.onload = function(){
    // readyState 4 means the request is done, and 200 is HTTP OK
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText),
            // The data we want to loop over
            x = json.beer,
            // This is how to make a new element
            table = document.createElement('table');

        // Set the classes
        table.className = "table table-bordered";

        // Loop over your data
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            // Create the HTML for this row
            var row = '<tr>' +
                '<td>'+x[i].name+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+x[i].type+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+x[i].company+'</td>' +
                // For a hyperlink, just use an `<a>` tag
                '<td><a href="'+x[i].website+'">'+x[i].website+'</a></td>' +
                '<td>'+x[i].price.toFixed(2)+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';

            // Let's just simply append to the table's innerHTML
            table.innerHTML += row;
        }

        // Add the table to the page
        document.body.appendChild(table);
    }
};

// This defaults to being *asynchronous*
xhr.open("GET","catalog.json");

// Start the request
xhr.send();
```